# eclipse libraries no longer working

Tags: eclipse, libraries

i had put two libraries on the build path of my project, and then i closed eclipse for the night. when i re-opened eclipse, and opened the same workspace, the libraries "aren't working" in that eclipse isn't doing any of the helpful things it was previously doing, like underlining bad syntax with red squigglies, reporting things that didn't get imported, etc. anyone have an idea of what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Project->Clean. Perhaps the perspective has changed, e.g. from one language to another so it isn'd doing any syntax highlighting

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have disabled "Project->Build Automatically"?